# Bootstrap drop-down menu not visible in mobile mode

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When I'm in PC mode with my big screen my menu created with Bootstrap, appears correctly without any problems.
However when I reduce my browser to mobile view and I click on the menu at the top right the components of my menu do not appear.

Here are the views:

Normal mode:

[Normal mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO98R.png)

In mobile mode:

Figure 1 :

[mobile mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViquL.png)

Figure 2 :

[mobile mode 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0txh.png)

As you can see, the contents of the menu is gone.
My Script :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="fr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">



<h:head>

    <title>Site FRC</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8"/>

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"></h:outputStylesheet>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <style type="text/css">

        body {
            background-color: #aaa;
            padding-top: 10px;
        }

        [class*="col-"] {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }


        .well {
            background-color: #CCC;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        a:active, a:focus {
            outline: none;
        }

        .inline-form input {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100px;
        }



    </style>


</h:head>

<h:body>


    <div class="container">

    <ui:include src="/template/common/commonHeader.xhtml" />


        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable col-lg-6">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215;</button>
            <strong>Information : </strong> Le site web est toujours en cours de
            développement
        </div>


        <br /> <br /><br /> <br /><br />




        <p:chart type="bar" model="#{chartView.barModel}" style="height:300px" />

        <p:chart type="bar" model="#{chartView.horizontalBarModel}"
                    style="height:300px" />




        <br/> <br/><br/>





    <ui:include src="/template/common/commonFooter.xhtml" /> 



    </div>


    <h:outputScript name = "/js/bootstrap.js" /> 
    <h:outputScript name = "/js/bootstrap..min.js" /> 




</h:body>

</html>
```

Edit here is my menu script :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>


    <meta charset="utf-8"/>

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>



</h:head>

<h:body>

<ui:composition>

<!--Menu déroulant-->


      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">   
        <div class="navbar-header">   
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.xhtml">FRC</a>
        </div>



        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li> <a href="index.xhtml">Accueil</a> </li>

            <li class="dropdown"> 
              <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Tableaux de données <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="dropdown-header">Consultation</li>          
              <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-screenshot"></span> Tout consulter</a></li>
              <li><a href="tableauxFiltrage.xhtml"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-screenshot"></span> Par filtrage</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Exporter</li>
              <li><a href="ExporterDonnee.xhtml"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> Exporter les données</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li> 

            <li class="dropdown"> 
              <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Graphiques <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="dropdown-header"> Génerale</li>
              <li><a href="graphiqueEvolution.xhtml"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-screenshot"></span> Evolution</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header"> Autres</li>
              <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> Autres</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li> 

            <li> <a href="#">Contact</a> </li>

          </ul>

          <h:form class="navbar-form navbar-right inline-form" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <h:inputText id="search" value ="" class="input-sm form-control" placeholder="Recherche"></h:inputText>
              <h:commandButton  value="Rechercher" onclick = "alert('Hello World!');"  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Chercher</h:commandButton>
            </div>
          </h:form>

        </div>
      </nav>


<!--Menu déroulant-->

</ui:composition>



</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simply the pattern of bootstrap 's mobile menu. When you click in the sqare that replace the menu, the menu will appear if you applied the scripts correctly. Just like that.

See this link above:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpWlaOeGZ_4

Comment: I follow the same script but when i click in the button to show the menu , nothing happen ..

Comment: Just like claudio I too thought the user was complaining about the hamburger icon. The problem the OP is complaining about is the fact the menu is not visible when the menu is expanded

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
My appologies, I thought you were complaining about the button.

Ok, it might be possible that you do not have the `show` property.

In your CSS where the nav items are, add this

`.collapse.show {
    display: block;
}`

This might work

Comment: yes, as my original post, you need to delete the `collapse` class. See my updated answer

Comment: i edit my post to show you the change but i really wanted to keep the button to show my menu in the mobile mode .. :/

Comment: Ohh I understand. The menu is missing from the dropdown.

Comment: I m working with bootstrap.css CDN , but when i added ur script to my xhtml page it still the same , doesn't work for me :/

Comment: Why don't you check in the inspector whats going on?

Comment: Ok i will check it

Answer (score 0):

If you are aware about the behavior of the bootstrap menu that disapear in small screen and turns into a little square when clicked shows the menu.
Check out if you have some transparent div or another html element covering your menu after the resizing browser for small screens. If you have some HTML element covering its, it blocks your clicking on the menu.

Comment: No i dont have additional div or something else .. :/